# C# - How can I limit data retrieved when displaying pin on map

Tags: c#, database, web, filter, request

I don't have any clue on how to start this.

I have a listing of places saved with Lont/Lat in DataBase.
I will shortly have several thousands or even millions of record and I want to display them on a map.

How could I avoid retrieving thousands of records' data when I will cluster them on the map (if several places are in the same area [so based on the zoom level] a pin with the number of element underneath will be displayed).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Google "HeatMap".

Google Maps provides a facility which will draw a pin with a number in it, rather than showing hundreds of pins.

As for only requesting a limited number of database records, you should use the TOP function in your SQL statement (or use .Take(n) if using EF).

If you limit your query to return, say, 100 records, then you could show something on your map to say "over 100 records returned".

You should also look into storing your data in a Geometry format, which will allow retrieval based on lat/lon+range queries.

Comment: "HeatMap" is a good starting point. Thank you.

Comment: But limiting the number or result will not allow to have an overview how the data should are scatered on the map.
I'll have a look at that Geometry format you have mentioned.